# why can't it allow "<%@ include file" inside a HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Ok, I got this jsp file & it works ok

```
<html>
<head><title>Account</title></head>
<body>
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I got a servlet

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
   resp.getWriter().println("<html>"+

                    "<head><title>Account</title></head>"+
                    "<body>"+

                    "<%@ include file=\"header.jsp\" %>"+

                    "</body"+
                    "</html>"
    }
```

The servlet print out `<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>` as a text on the page & could not understand that it is a `<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>`.

*How can let servlet to print out the result exactly like the jsp file I mentioned above?*

Comment: Because a JSP file isn't the same thing as a response string. A JSP is turned into a servlet, and directives/tags do things. Here you're sending a string to the client-the client knows nothing about JSP. Why are you generating HTML in a servlet in the first place?

Comment: @DaveNewton, how to avoid generating html from servlet?

Comment: Use JSP (or other view-layer technology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/header.jsp").include(request, response);
```

But you should avoid this type of a situation.